# Unable to add a source with url for private repo

Tags: ios, terminal, cocoapods, bitbucket

When I want to install pods from private repo and run `pod install`, I'm getting a following error:

```
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://bitbucket.org/mycompany/pods.git` named `bitbucket-some-pods`.
You can try adding it manually in `/Users/myusername/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
```

I've tried to `pod setup`, add it manually, renew SSH keys, tried to install having source urls inside of Podfile both as ssh and htmls. Nothing helped.

Comment: SSH keys are irrelevant if you define the source as HTTPS. Where are you defining the credentials for HTTPS access?

Comment: @JimRedmond I just tried both ways. Credentials for HTTPS are either in keychain or it is asked every time in terminal, I can tell you exactly if you need it, but what is it important for?

Comment: Did you try to follow the advice shown in line #2 of your output? It's quite well documented here: https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html

Comment: @Tom as I wrote in the description, yes I tried to add it manually and via `pod repo add`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had a few Git credentials stored on the system and they got mixed up somehow. I've found a credentials manager this way:

```
$ git config --system --list
```

It's shown this: `credential.helper=osxkeychain`

So, I followed steps below:

1. Opened Keychain Access
2. Searched keys for **github.com**
3. Removed all found keys
4. Restarted the laptop
5. Done